# Закруглить Image

Tags: c#, wpf

Не получается правильно закруглить изображение.

```
<Border CornerRadius="5">
<Image x:Name="NewsImageControl" Stretch="Fill" Cursor="Hand" />
</Border>
```

Пробовал конечно же использовать:

```
<Image.Clip>
<EllipseGeometry Center="100,100" RadiusX="200" RadiusY="200" />
</Image.Clip>
```

Ничего нормального из этого конечно же не происходит

Answer (score 5):

Да способов, по сути, куча. Если брать ваш пример, то `EllipseGeometry` стоит заменить на `RectangleGeometry`, который позволит закруглить углы, ну и задать правильные размеры. Выйдет примерно так:

```
<Image Width="200" Height="200" Stretch="UniformToFill"
       Source="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgkgAZ0YSM6q6tdBIq0CyGE9M8ekszuCz5485GabA=k-s328">
    <Image.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Rect="0,0,200,200"/>
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

[image: Image Clip Result]

Можем пойти чуть другим путем и сделать на основе маски, то есть нам нужен объект, который подойдет в качестве маски для изображения, выглядеть будет тогда так:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="200">
    <Border x:Name="Mask" Background="Red" CornerRadius="20" Margin="5"/>
    <Image Source="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgkgAZ0YSM6q6tdBIq0CyGE9M8ekszuCz5485GabA=k-s328">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}"/>
        </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Из плюсов, этот пример не привязан как-либо к размерам, но из минусов, цвет маски может заходить за пределы изображения. Для исправления этого недостатка тут `Margin` на ней, без него будет так:

[image: Border mask result]

Видно думаю, что изображение в некой красной рамке.

Есть более радикальный (и как по мне самый лучший) способ, это сделать свой `Border`, который будет сам следить за закруглением контента внутри себя.

- Пишем в поисковике "wpf border cornerradius content" и находим например [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325003) ответ.
- Копируем код в проект, подправляем все под себя.
- В XAML пишем:

  ```
  <local:ClippingBorder CornerRadius="20">
      <Image Source="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgkgAZ0YSM6q6tdBIq0CyGE9M8ekszuCz5485GabA=k-s328" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
  </local:ClippingBorder>
  ```
- Подправляем под себя как надо и получаем такой же результат, что и выше без каких-либо масок и лишних компонентов.

Если нужно вообще полностью закруглить изображение, то лучше поступить так:

```
<Ellipse Height="200" Width="200">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgkgAZ0YSM6q6tdBIq0CyGE9M8ekszuCz5485GabA=k-s328"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Результатом будет полноценный круг, но именно закругленные углы вы тут вряд-ли получите.

[image: Image in circle]

Вот, собственно, и основные пути решения данной задачи.