# Как закруглить углы у Image в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Пытаюсь закруглить края у Image или сделать объект полностью круглым разными способами, включая использования RectangularGeometry и т. д., но картинка в итоге обрезается с правай и нижней сторон вместо закругления. При этом в Visual Studio все отображается нормально, проблема появляется только при сборке. Вот один из способов, которым я пытался реализовать закругление.

```
    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Margin="75,79,675,655">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/zDhKKcqBHQ-lorJi7BP-apNjV_S-B7FXF8utPGcPg_62a61YxvUUfsTlZFjp4tvxdvYHaBHsmQ1IyPI72xapId4s.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
```

[image: Вот так выглядит в IDE]
[image: Вот так выглядит после запуска программы]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1164862/220553 `Margin="75,79,675,655"` - это бред, не должно быть такого

Comment: Этот способ тоже пробовал, если копировать код полностью и кроме картинки ничего не менять, то работает, но если изменить размер (в моем случае 100x100 вместо 200x200) и переместить объект в нужное место в окне (поэтому там Margin), то картинка также обрезается.

Comment: Ну потому что вы обрезаете ее отступами, научитесь позиционировать объекты грамотно!

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, теперь все работает.